# jsf 2 @managedProperty never set in wildfly 8

Tags: java, jsf-2, wildfly-8

Working on a mockup using this bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="login")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

private String login ;
private String pwd ;

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getPwd() {
    return pwd;
}
public void setPwd(String pwd) {
    this.pwd = pwd;
}
```

After a dummy login, I need to use my @managedProperty in order to set my next bean :

```
//Only for proving concepts
@ManagedProperty(value="#{login}")
private LoginBean loginBean;

public LoginBean getLoginBean() {
    return loginBean;
}

public void setLoginBean(LoginBean loginBean) {
    this.loginBean = loginBean;
}
```

The bean I need to set my nextPage calls this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  if (loginBean.getLogin()) {
     ...
  }
}
```

but this bean stays null:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at fr.maf.vega.web.control.RechercheDossierBean.init(RechercheDossierBean.java:441)
```

Thank you for your advices...

Note:
using the following method for getting the @SessionScoped loginBean works well (but it doesn't seem to belong to the best practices):

```
 public static Object getManagedBean(final String beanName) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Object bean;

    try {
        ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
        bean = elContext.getELResolver()
                .getValue(elContext, null, beanName);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new FacesException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    if (bean == null) {
        throw new FacesException(
                "Managed bean with name '"
                        + beanName
                        + "' was not found. Check your faces-config.xml or @ManagedBean annotation.");
    }

    return bean;
}
```

Comment: Is your SessionScoped annotation from javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped ?

Comment: Have you tried to initialize LoginBean somewhere in your code before use it?

Comment: My LoginBean is previously initialized from a dedicated page

Comment: Jaqen, my SessionScoped is javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped